# Canvasjs - Missing axis numbers and second dataset legend

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, canvasjs

https://jsfiddle.net/ma0s5d7x/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var twoPoints = [];
var tenPoints = [];
jQuery.getJSON("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/USTREASURY/YIELD.json?api_key=XXXX&collapse=weekly", function(results) {  
    $.each(results.dataset.data, function(key, value){
        twoPoints.push({x: new Date(value[0]), y: parseFloat(value[5])});
        tenPoints.push({x: new Date(value[0]), y: parseFloat(value[9])});
    });
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title:{
            text:"Treasurey Yield Curve Rates"
        },
        axisX:{
            valueFormatString: "YYYY",
            interval: 2
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Rate"
        },
        toolTip: {
            shared: true
        },
        data: [{
            name: "2YR",
                showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "2YR",
            type: "line",
            xValueFormatString: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            dataPoints : twoPoints
        },
        {
            name: "10YR",
                showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "10YR",
            type: "line",
            xValueFormatString: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            dataPoints : tenPoints
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
});
```

});

I've set my legend and data-sets to display in the legend and also show the values on the x axis but nothing is showing up.  Does anyone have an idea as to why their being ignored by the 1st data-set is showing up fine?

Comment: Legend seems to be working fine and its showing up "2YR" and "10YR" as you are setting legendText, check this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/j9apu0)

Also you are using an older version of CanvasJS (v1.7) whereas current version is v2.1.1. Please describe your issue properly, so that we can understand it better and help you out!

Comment: Huh, I thanks for making me aware - I guess CDNJS doesn't have the most latest. I updated to the most recent file and I could see both 2YR and 10YR.  Prior I could only see the 2YR label.  Thank you Vishwas!

Comment: Ross Bethune, glad that its working fine. However even with v1.7.0 i could see both 2YR and 10YR being shown. Here is the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/j9wlwl)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have the most recent canvasjs file.